# Как создать .apk файл с помощью buildozer в Windows?

Tags: python, android, ubuntu, apk, buildozer

При попытке создания файла **.apk** через **buildozer** столкнулся с проблемой, что если это делать в **Windows**, то не создается **target android**, это видно если прописать в терминале `buildozer help`. Если создать виртуальную машину с **Ubuntu**, то там этой проблемы нет, но пока не хотелось бы переходить на неё, рано ещё. Вероятно проблема из-за того, что надо установить модуль **python-for-android**, но он не доступен для Windows, если я правильно понял.

*Это моя первая попытка использования buildozer, ubuntu и виртуальных машин*, так что уже мозг кипит, возможно не понимаю какой-то нюанс.

Кто-нибудь знает как добавить отдельно **target** для **android**?
Или установить модуль **python-for-android**, если дело в нём?
Или может подскажете гайд, где пошагово показана работа **buildozer** именно для Windows? Не нашел такого гайда, а по официальной документации почему-то не выходит добиться результата.

В крайнем случае - подскажите пожалуйста как еще можно создать **.apk** файл из python именно в **Windows**? Игра на **pygame**, если это важно.

Первый скрин - терминал PyCharm в Windows, второй - в Ubuntu
[image: терминал Windows]

[image: терминал Ubuntu]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отвечу сам. Заодно памятка будет на будущее.

1. Вместо виртуальных машин устанавливаем Windows Subsystem for Linux (**WSL**) - правой кнопкой на меню пуск, WindowsPowerShell (администратор), `wsl --install`, перезагрузка. [***Подробная инструкция тут***.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)
2. Переходим в папку с проектом через консоль WSL. Или открываем путь к ней в проводнике и на папке, в которой находит основной файл программы (или внутри этой папки на пустом месте), и нажимаем сочетание **Shift+ПКМ**. В контекстном меню добавится новый пункт "*Откройте здесь оболочку Linux*", нажимаем туда.

**ВАЖНО!!!** В названии папки с main.py не должно быть пробелов. А основной файл должен называться именно **main.py** (можно будет изменить это требование на 5 шаге)

3. Вводим команду (чтобы вставить в консоль скопированный текст нажмите в ней *правую кнопку мыши*):

```
sudo apt update
```

Если в конце её работы видим ошибки вроде:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

то по [**этой инструкции**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) поочередно вводим команды

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
sudo apt update
```

Eесли ошибок нет, но в последней строке написано что-то вроде

```
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

то напишите

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update
```

Вроде как это необязательно, но на мой взгляд лучше обновить.

4. Продолжаем поочередно вводить команды [**отсюда**](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#android-on-windows-10-or-11):

```
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-17-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.33 virtualenv 
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
pip3 install --user --upgrade buildozer
buildozer init
```

5. В папке появится файл настроек, который можно редактировать хоть блокнотом, хоть IDLE. В строке с зависимостями добавьте импортируемые модули. В моем случае вместо `kivy` нужны `pygame`, `pygame-menu` и `typing-extensions`. Там же можно поменять название, автора, ориентацию и т.д. В официальной документации [**buildozer**](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications.html) и [**python-for-android**](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1) достаточно подробно описано.

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,pygame,pygame-menu,typing-extensions
```

На мой взгляд этот пункт самый важный, так как у меня приложение вылетало пока я не добавил последний модуль `typing-extensions`. Он нужен из-за модуля `pygame-menu`, но на ПК и без него работает, а его добавление для андроида нигде не документируется. Чтобы это понять мне пришлось узнать что такое Android Studio, logcat, виртуальное устройство, расшифровка логов и т.д. Остальные пункты удобнее настраивать когда приложение уже запускается и можно смотреть разницу при их изменении в разных сборках. Но если накосячить тут, то запустить не получится.

Закрываем файл, сохранив изменения.

6. Вводим команду для начала создания **.apk** файла:

```
buildozer android debug
```

В примерах регулярно советуют добавлять `deploy run`, но если вы не подключали заранее устройство, то не нужно этого делать. Без этих команд скомпилируется `.apk` файл, который уже сами скинете куда надо.
В первый раз в процессе создания файла надо будет 2 раза ввести `y`, чтобы согласиться с условиями лицензии. Файл `.apk` будет в папке `bin`, дальше его можно скидывать на телефон или виртуальное устройство.

Лично я в `buildoser.spec` [**прописал**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1502407/525526) `bin_dir = /mnt/h/ЯДиск` где ЯДиск- папка, автоматически синхронизирующая все содержимое с облаком. Сразу же после создания файла он оказывается в этой папке (или перезаписывает предыдущую версию) и отправляется в облако. Остается открыть облако на телефоне и запустить синхронизированный `.apk` для установки. Самый удобный метод без использования кабелей, что я смог придумать. Можно еще вроде Android Studio соединить с телефоном по Wi-Fi и тогда уже разворачивать приложение автоматически после сборки, но не каждый телефон поддерживает такую синхронизацию

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое дополнение к памятке для тех кому лень читать инструкции:

Цитата:

> Скопируйте каталог вашего проекта Kivy из раздела Windows в раздел WSL и следуйте инструкциям по быстрому запуску. Не переходите в каталог проекта в разделе Windows и не выполняйте сборку там, это может привести к неожиданным и непонятным сбоям.