# Как правильно указать путь к папке Windows в Linux внутри WSL?

Tags: wsl, wsl2

Есть текстовый файл, в котором нужно правильно прописать путь в определенную папку на другом физическом диске. **Linux** (если точнее, то **WSL** под windows) должен открыть этот файл и в указанной папке сделать свои дела. Вопрос - как правильно указать этот путь, чтобы **WSL** творил свою магию именно там? Просто перейти туда не вариант, надо именно находясь в одной папке считать из текстового файла путь к другой папке.

То есть если прописать что-то вроде `H:\сюда`, то в исходной папке появится новая папка `H··сюда`, так как путь по адресу **windows** тут не подходит само собой. И уже в этой папке, вместо требуемой, будет дальнейший процесс происходить

Comment: Я думаю, что диск `H:` в WSL у вас смонтирован как `/mnt/h/`, соответственно папка называется `/mnt/h/сюда`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ ***Pak Uula***. Раз он ответил в комментарии, то отвечу тут сам, может кому пригодится. Правильный ответ: `/mnt/h/сюда`